# Showing a set is not a subspace via geometric interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\begin{pmatrix} x & y & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is not a subspace of $\bf{R}^3$.

I understand that is true since it does not contain the origin.

Since a span is by definition a subspace, then for a subspace $V$, there must be a set $S$ containing $\bf{R}^3$ vectors which spans $V$, *i.e.* $\operatorname{span}(S) = V$.

Conversely, if set $A = \begin{pmatrix} x & y & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is not a subspace, then there must not be a finite set $S$ containing $\bf{R}^3$ vectors where, $\operatorname{span}(S) = A$.

The points on a line $L$ on $A$ are linearly independent.
E.g. $L$ = { ( a 0 1) | a is real }, or
{ ( b 1  1 ) | b is real }, or
{ ( c 2 1 ) | c is real }

The plane $A$ contains an infinite number of lines parallel to and beside each other.

Therefore, it takes an infinite set to span $A$.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can see it is not a subspace by asking what happens if you add two such vectors together.  For example $(0,0,1)+(0,0,1)$ you would get $(0,0,2)$ which is outside of the set, or asking what happens if you multiply by a scalar... you get $2\cdot (0,0,1)=(0,0,2)$ is outside of the set.

Comment: It is accurate to say the spanning set of a non-subspace does not exist; it is not accurate to say it's infinite

Comment: Thanks Moravitz and Tanner. Here is my argument for the spanning set of a non-subspace being infinite : consider u =  ( 1 0 1 ) and v = ( 2 0 1  ). The set { u, v } is linearly independent. Extrapolating, S = { ( a 0 1 ) | a is real } is a linearly independent set. S is infinite since a is real. Geometrically, we are referring to the line  x = ( 0 0 1 ) + k ( 1 0 0 ) where k is real. Since there exists this line on the plane which cannot be spanned by a finite spanning set, then the plane z = 1 is not a subspace since it cannot be spanned by a finite set.